# How to take save a snapshot from my kinect to disk?

Tags: kinect, image-view, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to debug a problem with my Kinect not working right.

In the tutorial, there is a pretty standard way to view the camera stream:
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

Is there a similarly simple way to save a snapshot to disk?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9377/how-to-take-save-a-snapshot-from-my-kinect-to-disk?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Left clicking on the image in image_view will save a screenshot to the directory from which you started image_view in c-turtle and below.  In Diamondback, you have to right click for this behavior; this prevents a lot of accidental frame grabs.  :)

For example, if you were in */home/murph/code/topSecret* in your terminal and you ran `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color`, the image would be saved in that directory.

Images are titled *frame0000.jpg*, *frame0001.jpg*, and so on.

To read more, visit the [image_view wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view).

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you click on the picture in image_view, doesn't it save the picture?

Else, you can use [image_saver in the image_view package](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view#image_view.2BAC8-diamondback.image_saver).

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=[ your topic]
```

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-08**:
@raphael favier  this rosrun gives me a infinite amount of image si there a way to just take one picture?  and is there a way that i can put this in a code so when a publisher publishes something just then it take a picture?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-05-25**:
@ctguell You just have to control the rate of how frequent `rosrun` command runs.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding to @raphael favier 's answer, you can time capturing by:

```
term-1$ rosrun image_view image_saver image:=image_raw _save_all_image:=false _filename_format:=foo.jpg __name:=image_saver
```

Then only when you call the following, image files are generated:

```
term-2$ rosservice call /image_saver/save
```

Got a hint at [start-jsk/jsk_apc/#9](https://github.com/start-jsk/jsk_apc/issues/9).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-26**:
is there a way to add timestamp to the image ? like the pcd images u get from kinect?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-02-26**:
@Baumboon Please open a new question.